# БД или файлы?

Tags: база-данных, файлы

Я знаю, что основная проблема файлов - это открытие сразу всего, и выдирание нужного, из-за чего теряется скорость, потому что объём загрузки большой.

Что же будет, если хранить каждый материал в отдельном файле, и алгоритмами доставать данные? Чисто теоретически, будет ли это быстрее базы данных?

Answer (score 2):

> основная проблема файлов - это
> открытие сразу всего, и выдирание
> нужного, из-за чего теряется скорость,
> потому что объём загрузки большой.

Нет, не это :) Совсем не обязательно всё хранить внутри файлов, "эмулирующих" БД. Хранить там можно, например идентификаторы файлов с контентом, а сами данные вынимать из них по мере необходимости.

А вот относительно сложная логика работы - это уже проблема. Без БД можно задолбаться с какой-нибудь выборкой по непростому условию, да с джойнами, на с груп бай, которая в SQL делается одной левой...

В качестве любопытного примера можно посмотреть, например, на [GetSimple CMS](http://get-simple.info/). Там всё организовано в виде XML-хранилищ, ничё, живёт и даже работает :)

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от способа работы с данными.

Предположим, что данные - это тяжелые изображения (bmp, tiff и т.п.), каждое изображение характеризуется уникальным именем (xxx.xxx). Предположим, что обращение к изображению всегда осуществляется по этому имени. Нужна ли в этом случае какая-либо особенная база данных?

SQL-база данных не нужна, потому что не нужен язык запросов; NoSQL-база может быть и нужна, а может быть и не нужна: в самом деле, обращение к файлу по имени в подходящей файловой системе (xfs) достаточно быстро, операционная система может сама кэшировать часто извлекаемые файлы в памяти.

Необходимость в базе возникает тогда, когда появляется потребность в чем-либо сверх того минимума, который дает файловая система.

Comment: Вот тут напрашивается очевидное: ФС может быть эффективней как минимум в 2 случаях. При работе с парами ключ/значение и при работе с графами/деревьями...

Answer (score 0):

Есть так называемая [SQLite](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) бд, она хранит бд в отдельном файле, из названия понятно что она поддерживает язык SQL. Работать с ней достаточно легко, в каждом языке программирования есть драйвера для работы с ней, в отличие от других SQL баз она не требует отдельного демона.

Comment: Я не просил порекомендовать БД, которая хранит всё в одном файле.

Comment: Да и вообще не просил ничего рекомендовать.

Answer (score 0):

Угу файлы, хочу достать всех учеников закончивших школу в 96 году, с тройкой по географии и остававшихся на второй год. Имею папку в которой лежит 1500 файлов. Каждый файл = записи об одной школе. Вы теперь предлагаете самостоятельно писать парсер/регэкспить это, а не написать двухстрочный  Select, который вызовет уже написанный алгоритм поиска на сервере, который уже лет 30 оптимизируют огромная толпа программистов по всему миру.

Comment: А разве не очевидно, что задачи разные бывают? И что хранилище/инструменты нужно проектировать заранее...

Comment: Поэтому пишут каждый раз разный запрос. А чтобы заранее проектировать хранилище есть другой запрос CREATE TABLE и ADD. Это удобнее чем писать под каждую задачу очередной код.

Comment: А какое всё это отношение имеет к обсуждаемому вопросу? Если вам не доводилось встречать эффективную работу с грамотно организованными хранилищами в файлах, это не значит, что её не может быть вообще, и что БД - универсальная затычка ко всему на свете.

Comment: Спасибо, единственный ответ по теме.